# Open div instead of infowindow by clicking marker on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a full screen Google Map that has a small div at the bottom to hold images that turn markers on and off. I also have a hidden div that holds information for each marker (that would normally appear in the infowindow).

I want to be able to show() or fadein() the hidden div when the marker is clicked on the map. This is how I am adding markers.

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][2]),
icon: icons[locations[i][4]].icon,
map: map,
id: locations[i][3],
type: locations[i][4]
});
markerGroups[locations[i][4]].push(marker);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
toggleWindow(marker.id);
})(marker, i));
bounds.extend(myLatLng);
}
if (locations.length > 0){
map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Each location in the array looks like this:
["1.50 inches", 37.5, -77.33, 0, "hail150"]

The toggle window function is:

```
function toggleWindow(id){
var godiv = '#sr'+id;
if ($(godiv).css('display') == 'block') {
$(godiv).css('display', 'none');
}
else {
$("#reportframe").children().hide(); 
$(godiv).css('display', 'block');
};
};
```

When you click on a marker I get an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined (main.js:17)

I have tried it several different ways but it appears that the IDs are not matching up or GMaps doesn't have access to the var.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7my0qsyc/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function-**call** which has been used as `click`-handler must **return a function**(the returned function will be the handler). Currently the function will return nothing, and the "nothing" is the `undefined` in the error-message.

so it has to be e.g:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
return function(){toggleWindow(marker.id);}
})(marker, i));
```

#### SEE DEMO

Comment: Thank you. That was the perfect answer and fixes everything up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your anonymous function closure.  It works for me if I use a `createMarker` function to create the closure.

```
function createMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[1], location[2]),
        icon: icons[location[4]].icon,
        map: map,
        id: location[3],
        type: location[4]
    });
    markerGroups[location[4]].push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        var godiv = '#sr' + marker.id;
        if ($(godiv).css('display') == 'block') {
            $(godiv).css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            $("#reportframe").children().hide();
            $(godiv).css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
  return marker;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
// add markers
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  var marker = createMarker(locations[i]);
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7my0qsyc/2/)